# Can a modded Xbox still play official games and connect to Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-360

I have a 4 GB Xbox with Kinect. I am  JTAGing my Xbox, along with installing a new 320GB hard drive. I have bought a few games in the past, and I want to know if I will still be able to play them on Xbox Live after modding my Xbox.

Comment: Do you mean "format" the hard drive? Or are you talking about installing modded firmware?

Comment: I mean to install a new XBOX compatible 320 gb hard drive

Comment: I'm still not sure what your question is. Are you asking about formatting your 4GB disk or your new, larger disk? Why are you wondering if you can still play games after? (What are you worried will happen?) Are you asking about games that have been installed to the 4GB disk, games that you downloaded, or both?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Look closely at ' I am replacing the default hard drive with a larger capacity disk.' I don't know why he needs to flash/format the internal 4GB flash memory if he is to install the 320HDD.

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 That's why I'm asking them to clarify. They may have misapprehensions that could be brought to light and corrected.

Comment: Well, that clarification definitely completely changes what I thought the question was about! @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108

Comment: Lol @SevenSidedDie yeah me too I've never jtagged my 360. But I would guess you would be losing your licenses. Once the jtagged 360 hits live there's always the chance that Microsoft will see the changes and poof! Banned 360. Personally that's what's stopped me in the past, the home brew might be worth it but my longtime membership and countless dlcs are not.

Comment: Close voters: This seems to be on-topic as per the ff: [meta] posts: [What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258/4797), [Should questions like “How can I install Firefox on the PS3?” be allowed?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3366/4797) and [How should we deal with direct questions on hardware modding?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3877/4797)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can play legit games online but if accidentally log on with a cracked game in you will be banned? That was my understanding. I don't think it's worth the risk going online with a flashed Xbox. Personally.

Comment: Hey Robyn. Great Answer, But get some concrete proof, if you can, the downside is that we all have seen people play on jtagged 360's, (Look at World at War and Modern Warfare 2) but the problem lies in current popular games where the devs are actively supporting it. As someone who's looked into this wayyyyy too many times, I can say that Modern games, **EVEN IF PURCHASED LEGALLY** can cause a jtagged 360 to get busted. It's the modified firmware and with the 360's update scheduled soon I would say its not worth it to make it a paper weight.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you can play official games of JTAG and connect to xbox live. I've done it already. :)